Relationship between a differential form and the tangent plane
Consider a point $(1, 2, 3) \in \Bbb R^3$, if we consider an exterior form of degree $1$, given by
$$w=\sum_{i=1}^3 a_{i} dx_{i}$$
So, for our case
$$
w(1, 2, 3) = \sum_{i=1}^3 a_{i}(1, 2, 3) \, dx_{i(1, 2, 3)} := a_{1}(1, 2, 3) \, dx_{(1, 2, 3)} + 2 \, a_{2}(1, 2, 3) \, dy_{(1, 2, 3)} + 3 \, a_{3}(1, 2, 3) \, dz_{(1, 2, 3)}
$$
If we try to take the kernel of that application for that point, we could make a particular case and find the points $x_1,$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ for which
\begin{align*}
   dx_{(1, 2, 3)} (x_1, x_2, x_3)=0 &\implies dx_{(1, 2, 3)} (x_{1}(1, 0, 0)+x_{2}(0, 1, 0)+x_{3}(0, 0, 1))=0\\
    &\implies x_{1}dx_{(1, 2, 3)}(1, 0, 0)+x_{2}dx_{(1, 2, 3)}(0, 1, 0)+x_{3}dx_{(1, 2, 3)}(0, 0, 1)=0
\end{align*}
Here, starting from kronecker's delta function, i.e. knowing that $dx_{i}(e_{j})=0$ if $i \neq j$ and $dx_{i}(e_{j})=1$ if $i = j$ Perhaps I could state that $0+x_2+x_3=0$
And it would get a value that belongs to the kernel of that application, say $v \in \mathbb{R}_{(1, 2, 3)}^3$, we could state that
$$w(p) \cdot v=0?$$
My main idea of all this is to consider the tangent plane of a surface associated to the point $(1, 2)$ and determine what relation has the kernel of the application, with that tangent plane searched. Any idea or suggestion that helps me to get this idea on track, it was an idea subtly mentioned by my professor, but I can't find the right formalization to express it.
Thanks!

For tangent vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$, $w(x)(v) = a_1(x)v_1 + a_2(x)v_2 + a_3(x)v_3$. Hence the kernel of $w(x)$ is the set of vectors orthogonal to $a(x)$.

@Kakashi I don't understand very well yet, what role plays that vector $v \in \Bbb R ^3$, which I guess lives in the tangent plane, can you help me a little bit, thanks for your comment!

$w(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{3}a_i(x),dx_i$ is a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}$. The kernel of $w(x)$ is ${v \in \mathbb{R}^3 : w(x)v = 0}$.

@Kakashi A question that might be easy to answer, but in  $w(x)(v) = a_1(x)v_1 + a_2(x)v_2 + a_3(x)v_3$ what happened to $\left. dx_i \right|_{x}$

Answer: $dx_i\big|_x(v) =v_i$.
